# Programmatically adding list to datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have procedure that programmatically adding list to datagridview. For Example:

```
public List<Color_INFO> addrowtocolors()
{    
    List<Color_INFO> result = dal.GetColor();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
         var index = grdColors.Rows.Add();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Code"].Value = result[i].Code.ToString();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Desc"].Value = result[i].Desc.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when I call it is adding 3 same rows to datagridview , and in list i have only one.

I know that I can use dataset option , but that not fit for my needs.

Thanx.

Comment: apart from using `list` to iterate` you don't use it at all.. are you sure that `list` and `result` hold the same values? I suspect it should either be `result.Count` as iterator, or `list[i]` as element lookup

Comment: So, where have you assigned `list` and `result[]` and why returning null if this method could be `void`?

Comment: I changed post,add assigned to code, and change procedure to void in code. Thanx for sugestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment... I've also removed the return value as it seemed strange to just return null. (or even the proposed list based on your function name).

```
public void addrowtocolors()
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
         var index = grdColors.Rows.Add();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Code"].Value = result[i].Code.ToString();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Desc"].Value = result[i].Desc.ToString();
    }
}
```

or

```
public void addrowtocolors()
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
         var index = grdColors.Rows.Add();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Code"].Value = list[i].Code.ToString();
         grdColors.Rows[index].Cells["Desc"].Value = list[i].Desc.ToString();
    }
}
```